# iOS How to set specifics channels of USB device to a audio player? AVFoundation

Tags: ios, audio, avfoundation, avaudioplayer, avaudiosession

I'm working with AVAudioplayer and AVAudiosession. I have got an iPad and a audio interface (sound card).

This audio interface has 4 outputs (2 stereo), a lightning cable and it receive energy from the iDevice, works excellent.

Ive coded a simple play() stop() AVAudioplayer that works fine BUT I need to asign specific channel of the audio interface (1-2 & 3-4). My idea is send two audios (A & B) to each output/channel (1-2 or 3-4)

I've read the AVAudioplayer's documentation and it says: `channelAssignments` is for asign channels to a audioplayer.

The problem is: I've created an AVAudiosession that get the data of the USBport's device plugged (soundcard). And I got:

```
let route = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().currentRoute

for port in route.outputs {
    if port.portType == AVAudioSessionPortUSBAudio {
        let portChannels = port.channels
        let sessionOutputs = route.outputs
        let dataSource = port.dataSources
        dataText.text = String(portChannels) + "\n" + String(sessionOutputs) + "\n" + String(dataSource)
    }
}
```

Log:
[outputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22GnA.jpg)

Which data I must to take and use to send the audios with `play()`?

Comment: Hi , how did you change the inputs ?
I mean I have apogee quartet , It has 4 analog inputs ,
How did you setting which inputs you want ???

Answer (score 0):

Wow - I had no idea that `AVAudioPlayer` had been developed at all since `AVPlayer` came out in iOS 4. Yet here we are in 2016, and `AVAudioPlayer` has `channelAssignments` while the fancy streaming, video playing with subtitles `AVPlayer` does *not*.

But I don't think you will be able to play two files `A` and `B` through one `AVAudioPlayer` as each player can only open one file. That leaves

1. creating two players (`player(A)` and `player(B)`) and setting the `channelAssignments` of each to one half of the audio devices output channels, dealing with the joys of synchronising the players, *or*
2. creating a four channel file, `AB`, and playing it through one player, assigning `channelAssignments` the full four channels you found above,  dealing with the joys of slightly non-standard audio files .

Sanity check: is your `session.outputNumberOfChannels` returning 4?

Personally, when I do this kind of thing I create a 4 channel remote io audio unit as I've found the higher level APIs cause too much heartache once you do anything a little unusual. I also use  `AVAudioSessionCategoryMultiRoute` because I don't have any > 2 channel sound cards, so I have to cobble headphone jack plus usb sound card to get 4 channels, but you shouldn't need this.

Despite not having procedural output  (like remoteIO audio units), you may also be able to use `AVAudioEngine` to do what you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Rhythmic Fistman for reply. 

First of all yes, I get `4` when I check the `outputNumberOfChannels`

And then, First: Yes, I need two player for A & B. But which data of the Session do I put into `channelAssignments` ?

Second, I didn't try that method. What do you mean "creating a four channel"? Am I creating a channel using Session?

Comment: I will read about `AVAudioEngine` Do you think is the best option? @Rhythmic